# Cannot find some fairseq parameters in docs

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, nlp, fairseq

I am using fairseq (version: 1.0.0a0+14c5bd0) to fine-tune a model as per [this link](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/tree/master/examples/mbart). However, there are lots of parameters used that I cannot find in the docs nor when I run `fairseq-train --help`. Examples include:

```
--warmup-updates
--encoder-normalize-before
--label-smoothing
```

Are they replaced by some other params?

Answer (score 0):

When you train your models, you can call general training parameters (documented in the [CLI help](https://fairseq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line_tools.html)) or component-specific parameters. You often need to look for the latter using the search bar on the top left of the [documentation site](https://fairseq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Concerning the specific ones you highlighted, some are documented with their components in the documentation:

- `--warmup-updates` is an attribute of the learning rate scheduler [(doc)](https://fairseq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lr_scheduler.html)
- `--encoder-normalize-before` is a Transformer model parameter [(doc)](https://fairseq.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.0/models.html#module-fairseq.models.transformer)

And some are documented only in the code (if at all):

- `--label-smoothing` is a parameter of the label-smoothed cross-entropy loss [(code)](https://fairseq.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.0/_modules/fairseq/criterions/label_smoothed_cross_entropy.html?highlight=--label-smoothing)

Comment: But I am confused on how I can set the warmup-updates, is it based on the number of epochs or the number of train steps? For example if I set the warmup-updates to 4000, will that use the warmup-init-lr for 4000 train steps or 4000 epochs?

Comment: In the code, it updates "the learning rate at the beginning of the given epoch." (with step_begin_epoch). This is another question than the one you originally asked, though.